# Does Unity compile scripts to c++?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, game-engine

**Does Unity compile C# scripts to C++?**
And generally how does running games in Unity work?

Comment: No. It would probably have decent performance, if it did.

Comment: @VTT probably because of IL2CPP and Burst.

Comment: @VTT Because it does if you use IL2CPP... See their [blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/06/an-introduction-to-ilcpp-internals/)

Comment: @nada You can use IL2CPP... it will convert C# to C++....

Comment: No it doesn't. Unity executes on C# virtual machine.

Comment: @LudovicFeltz Ooooorrrr I just write my code in C++ from the beginning.

Comment: @nada You can just write in C++ from the beginning. But you lose vast amounts of development iteration speed. The unity burst compiler offers "performance by default", with a nice job system. You can write something faster, but there's not many widely available engines that can compete with Unity's extensive tools library and Cpu performance combined right now, even engines that encourage writing native C++ for gamecode.

Comment: @George I'd love to discuss this further, but in practise you are proven correct by the vast amount of games that pop up which are made with unity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see a lot of comment here **that are totally WRONG. The answer is YES, you can convert C# code to C++ as an alternative to Mono if you are using IL2CPP.** (if you choose to in player params)

> When building a project using IL2CPP, Unity converts IL code from
>   scripts  and assemblies to C++, before creating a native binary file
>   (.exe, apk, .xap, for example) for your chosen platform. Some of the
>   uses for IL2CPP include increasing the performance, security, and
>   platform compatibility of your Unity projects.

You can see this [blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/06/an-introduction-to-ilcpp-internals/) on the Unity website about how it works.

Or the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP.html) for more informations on the subject

Comment: Sorry for the *link only* answer but i will not copy paste the content here

Comment: @nada I bet too :) but that's another subject ;)

Comment: Just a reminder: You haven't actually answered OP's embedded question _And generally how does running games in Unity works?_

Comment: @nada Do you have any background for the statements you are making? It appears to me that you are throwing around unfounded (and incorrect) guesses as facts. Please write an answer if you are sure of what you are saying and have sources to back you up.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Just a rule of thumb: _Additional layers of complexity add potential for additional problems_ (... and this sounds to me like it has huge complexity, just have a quick glimpse at the linked docs)

Comment: @nada The Sub-question *And generally how does running games in Unity works?* looks a little to broad to answer here... I just answer to *how does it convert C# to C++* would be more correct i think

Comment: Unity also offers the [Burst compiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.burst@0.2/manual/index.html#overview), I haven't used it extensively for any sort of long term project. But I have used it for a few smaller projects aswell as jams and it has worked great so far. Obviously it compiles straight to assembly so you do lose C++ symbols, not sure if that's really a problem though.

Comment: IL2CPP, just like Burst, is a form of AOT compilation, and regardless of method used the final output will still be a managed code using the same mono runtime. Also use of IL2CPP *reduces* security and platform compatibility.

Comment: @VTT for the security/compatibility part, i just quoted their documentation. And for the managed part it looks like it compile the generated C++ to native code dependent on the target platform see: the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP-HowItWorks.html)